# Symfony Submit button doesn't work IsSubmitted never verified

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm learning symfony 4 and I'm testing to see how to update a database by taking data from a form. It seems like isSubmitted's never verified.

Here is my Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("scheduler/new", name="scheduler_create")
 * @Route("scheduler/{id}/edit", name="scheduler_edit")
 */
public function form(Task $task = null, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager){

    if(!$task) {
        $task = new Task();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

        $manager->persist($task);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('scheduler_show', ['id' => $task-> getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('scheduler/create.html.twig', [
        'formTask' => $form->createView(),
        'editMode'=> $task->getId() !== null
    ]);
}
```

My view :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme formTask 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <h1> Création d'une tâche </h1>

    {{ form_start(formTask) }}

    <p> 
        Inscrire ici le nom souhaité pour la tâche : {{form(formTask.title, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : "Titre de la tâche"} }) }}
        Veuillez d'écrire l'objet de la tâche : {{form(formTask.content, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : "Description de la tâche"} }) }}
        Séléctionner le groupe destinataire de la tâche : {{form(formTask.groupe) }} 
    </p>
    <p> A quelle date et souhaitez vous executer la tâche ? {{form(formTask.launch_date) }} </p>
    {{form(formTask.activer) }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        {% if editMode %}
            Sauvegarder les modifications
        {% else %}
            Sauvegarder la tâche
        {% endif %}
    </button>


    {{ form_end(formTask) }}

{% endblock %}
```

I have been working with symfony for 2 weeks now so not that long.
I'm following an online tutorial, and it's working until now 
I can't see any error message and don't know how can i solve that.

Here is my FormType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Task;
use App\Entity\Groupe;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('launch_date', DateTimeType::class)
            ->add('content')
            ->add('activer')
            ->add('groupe', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Groupe::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title'
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Task::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Before handling the form try checking if the method is post and continue after that.

Comment: Also when you persist I think it should be `$manager->persist($form->getData())`

Comment: Just checking. Have you tried checking if there is any validation error on the for? Another thing you should check is extra form fields. Symfony doesn't like extra form fields but you can set a flag in `configureOptions` to allow extra fields. In addition, @MartinM. asked about post method. Did you ensure that the form is submiting via `post`? If it's not, the form will not be marked as submitted. Try `<input type="submit" >`, I don't think that will make any difference but worth a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for such a button to work it must be inside the `{{ form_start(your_form) }} {{ form_end(your_form) }}` twig tags

otherwise it will not count as a form submit button

you can go over this by using `$builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class);`

Edit after discussion:

To custom the rendering of form rows, `form_row(form.children)` should be used instead of `form(form.children)` as this is going to display every informations such as form errors.

for a more precise handling you can refer to [the symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)

Comment: Maybe i don't understant correctly but my button seems to be inse the start and end twig tags no ? I've tried to add $builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class); and nothing change

Comment: You did, i didn't had your full view when i wrote my answer.
Do something happen when you dump something between isSubmitted and isValid ?

Comment: and for the form errors, you have to use form_row(form.children) instead of form(form.children) or you can decompose using https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html for more precise handling

Comment: no problem, have fun :) i am going to edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem : i try to submit using the button, but it doesn't work ! i forgot to put a {{ form_start(my_form) }} ..... {{ form_end(my_form) }}

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow! This one serves as a comment and not an answer. If still don't have any reputation to make a comment, best to create your own question instead or wait for an answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32507843)